# strip between the last two dots

Tags: preg-match-all

I have a site where I want to script the uniqueid within the last two dots. I got something working ok but it's not 100%. Please help me if you have a chance, thank you!

When getting file_contents, you'll see something like this:

```
http://www.alkdjfsadf.com/masdfsdfv/i-want-to-grab-the-following.z3jTdIcaSlGR.html
```

I would only want links that has "masdfsdfv" in it to grab the ids...

I want to grab out: z3jTdIcaSlGR into a variable.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
$dp = "http://www.alkdjfsadf.com/masdfsdfv/grab-moi.html?page=1";
$sp = @file_get_contents($dp);

preg_match_all("(./(.*?).html/)", $sp, $content); 

foreach($content[0] as $surl) {
echo $nctid
}
```

Any kind of help I could get on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want:

```
preg_match_all('(/masdfsdfv/.*\\.(.*?)\\.html)', $sp, $content);
foreach ($content[1] as $surl) {
    echo $surl, "\n";
}
```

You had an extra `/` at the end of the URL, and forgot to escape the literal `.`. The list of matches of the capture group are in `$content[1]`, not `$content[0]`. And you were echoing `$nctid` instead of `$surl`.

Comment: we're close, but i don't need the entire file name, i just need the ids/text right before .html and after the 2nd to last . (dot)

Comment: it's giving me: i-want-to-grab-the-following.z3jTdIcaSlGR - i just want: z3jTdIcaSlGR - please see the url example I put above...

Comment: anyway we can make the search to make sure that here is two dots before it do the striping? I don't want just any url with .html to be in the list...

Comment: you are right, I didn't hit refresh... working great now, however i'm still getting text from links that does not have double dots...

Comment: I took the dot out of the URL, and it didn't match the regexp at all.